# Multiple AJAX calls for a table initialized more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The question is tricky so I'll post the context:

1. I have a fragment on the page that gets loaded via AJAX.
2. That page contains a table that will be powered and populated by Datatables *with server-side processing*.
3. Everytime I load the fragment that contains a new table, I tell Datatables to boot the table from scratch, using `bDestroy : true`.

#### Problem

The AJAX calls that fetch the data as JSON keep piling up as I load new tables via AJAX.

#### Question

How do I keep these calls from stacking up and reduce them to a single one? Thank you.

---

#### Code samples (upon request)

```
/* datatables initializer */

$("#table").dataTable({
  bDestroy : true
, bServerSide : true
, sAjaxSource : "path/to/json.json"
, ...
});

/* script inside the AJAX loaded content. It outputs a <table>. */

$(function() {
  $("body").trigger({ type : "tableready", options : { ... } });
});
```

Comment: paste some code so we see how all this is being done

Comment: What do you mean by `The AJAX calls that fetch the data as JSON keep piling up`? Are you creating new tables or updating one table with different data?

Comment: Updated with code. @wanovak, yes, the table gets outputed over the previous one via `$("#main").load("path/to/new/table.action",function() {})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is out of DataTables' responsability. The code sample above is missing the cause of the problem.

I have built a class that *binds* an event to a function that empowers the table. Everytime I invoked the AJAX call that retrieved the table, the function stacked another binding on top, hence the multiple calls for data.

The solution is either to check if you have already bound that event or to `unbind()` the event and re`bind()` it again.