# How can I have only one chart rendered upon an AJAX request?

Tags: ajax, extjs, charts

I am using ExtJS 4 to create charts. The charts are instantiated every time I make an AJAX call. Something like this:

```
$("#maincontent").getJSON("path/to/jsondata",function(data) {
  _chart.chart = Ext.create("Ext.chart.Chart", {
    axes   : _chart.axes()
  , style  : 'background:#fff'
  , series : _chart.series()
  , store  : _chart.store()
  , renderTo : $("#chart").get(0)
  , width  : Sybus.Utils.mainWidth()
  , height : Sybus.Utils.mainHeight()
  });
});
```

The more I invoke the AJAX call, the more charts I have on the page. How can I prevent this from happening and have only one chart? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763073/multiple-ajax-calls-for-a-table-initialized-more-than-once), I have adapted its answer to suit this context.*

The answer to this issue is out of ExtJS' responsability. The code sample above is missing the cause of the problem.

I have built a class that *binds* an event to a function that builds the chart. Everytime I invoked the AJAX call that retrieved the data for the chart, the function stacked another binding on top, hence the multiple charts.

The solution is either to check if you have already bound that event or to `unbind()` the event and re`bind()` it again.